# Are those hooks usable for hanging coats and hats?

Tags: design

I'm not sure whether this is the right site to ask for design of everyday things like this. I have found the following solution quite appealing and simplistic, however I have doubts whether it would be effective for hanging coats. I have impression coats can often fall down.

[image: Fancy hooks]

Particularly, comparing to traditional hooks, which also seem to store more: both hats and coats.

[image: Traditional hooks]

Can the first solution be designed in such a way, it is still simple but more functional?

Comment: One traditional solution is "Shaker pegs", which are straight pegs with a narrower section and a bulge at the end so things are less likely to slide off. That might or might not be enough to make this system work better.

Comment: Angling the pegs upward will provide a better potential energy well for coats and other heavy, bulky objects. Pegs straight out like that, the bulk of a down coat will will push the coat's collar right off the peg.

Comment: And kudos goes to does who downvoted without any constructive critic. This way I will ask bad questions again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent stuff from sliding off the poles, yet keep the same look, you can try spraying the exposed poles with some kind of clear rubberized coating [like this](http://amzn.com/B000LNN11G)

Comment: Spraying is one thing, but your answer suggested me that I could also look for another material than wood that is less slippery.